# How do we resize the JTabbedPane Buttons?

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I am using a `JTabbedPane` with three buttons. The program is running fine except that the buttons remains small even if you resize the window. Is there a way of `setPrefferedSize` for them?

Here is the code

```
public final class JTabbedPaneDemo {

    JFrame frame;
    JTabbedPane pane;
    JPanel panel1;
    JPanel panel2;
    JPanel panel3;


    JTabbedPaneDemo(){

    this.createFrameGUI("My Tabbed Pane");

    }
    //creating the frame
    public void createFrameGUI(String title){
    frame= new JFrame(title);
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(350,350));
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    //create the the tabs
    this.createPanel1();
    this.createPanel2();
    this.createPanel3();

    //create the tabbed pane
    pane= new JTabbedPane();
    pane.addTab("Pane 1", panel1);
    pane.addTab("Pane 2", panel2);
    pane.addTab("Pane 3", panel3);

    //add the pane to the frame
    frame.add(pane,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }


    //creating the tabs
    public void createPanel1(){
    panel1= new JPanel();
    panel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panel1.add(new JButton("we are in panel 1"));
    panel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));
    }
      public void createPanel2(){
    panel2= new JPanel();
    panel2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panel2.add(new JButton("we are in panel 2"));
    panel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));
    }
    public void createPanel3(){
    panel3= new JPanel();
    panel3.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panel3.add(new JButton("we are in panel 3"));
    panel3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));
    }
    public static void main(String [] args){

    JTabbedPaneDemo dem= new JTabbedPaneDemo();

    }
}
```

Comment: Buttons, where? On the tab itself on within the tabbed pane?

Comment: Show the code you're using. What layout are do you have in the tabbed view?

Comment: @MadProgrammer buttons on the tabbed pane itseft

Comment: What look do you want? Are you trying to have a tab consisting of a single button with 50 padding?

Comment: Don't screw with the panels preferred sizes

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils the default is fine at this stage. Yeah something like that - a way of expanding the button say to double its size - or to make it resize itself with respect to the window.

Comment: @MadProgrammer No i wont do that - i just wanted to clarify the issue here - i was saying the way we do it with components like frames, panels e.t.c

Comment: Looks like your code does just that. It creates a window with three tabs, all with a single button the size of the tab. When I re-size the window the button follows suite; not sure what you need.

Comment: To change the tabs themselves, you'd ned a custom `TabbedPaneUI`.

Answer (score 1):

I found what I have been looking for; perhaps someone would need this. I actually wanted to resize the **tabs**, I realized that **buttons** is a wrong term there.The following is a code that worked for me

```
mytabbedPane.addTab("<html><body leftmargin=15 topmargin=8 marginwidth=15 marginheight=5>Tab1</body></html>", new JLabel("Text Component 1"));
```

This will resize according to the values you input for margins.

Find the link with more details [here](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/xuanyun/archive/2009/01/change_the_tab.html).